# Links in iOS Ionic app not opening immediately

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a few links in one of the views in my app for:

1. Sharing
2. Adding to calendar
3. Opening an external link

On an iPhone which I used to test the app, 1 and 2 sort of work but only if I press the Home button and then return to the app, then the share/calendar dialogs appear. Can anyone suggest what could cause this? I'm not sure where to even look.

The external link uses window.open(url, "_system") because I was not able to get regular  type links to work in the simulator. I may switch back to regular HTML links though as another link was able to work on the test iPhone. What is the suggested method to open links in the phone's browser using iOS?

Code is roughly as below.

```js
.controller('WCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $sce) {
  // ...
  $scope.doShare = function () {
    var options = {
      message: 'Message here',
      subject: 'Event shared'
    };
    var onSuccess = function (result) {
      console.log('Share successful.');
    };
    var onError = function (msg) {
      console.log('Sharing failed with message: ' + msg);
    }
    window.plugins.socialsharing.shareWithOptions(options, onSuccess, onError);
  };
  $scope.doCalAdd = function () {
    var onSuccess = function (result) {
      console.log('Add to calendar successful.');
    };
    var onError = function (msg) {
      console.log('Add to calendar failed with message: ' + msg);
    }
    // ...
    window.plugins.calendar.createEventInteractively(
      title,
      location,
      notes,
      starttime,
      endtime,
      onSuccess,
      onError);
  };
  $scope.doTicketsOpen = function () {
    var url = w.ticketing;
    window.open(url, '_system');
  };
})
```

```html
<ion-view class="item-text-wrap" view-title="Event Details">
  <ion-content class="has-footer">
    <!-- ... -->
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer-bar>
    <div class="button-bar">
      <div class="button icon ion-share" ng-click="doShare();">Share</div>
      <div class="button icon ion-calendar" ng-click="doCalAdd();">Calendar</div>
      <div class="button icon ion-link" ng-click="doTicketsOpen();">Ticketing</div>
    </div>
  </ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
```

I have a Content-Security-Policy meta tag in the index.html as below.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

Comment: Do you have a Content-Security-Policy meta tag in your index.html? if you have it, can you post it?

Comment: @jcesarmobile, thanks I've added it in the post. I also tried to search in that direction. Seems I may need to add gap: in default-src?

Comment: Yes, you have to add `gap:` to make plugins work on iOS 10, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316548/phonegap-build-app-inappbrowser-window-is-not-shown-automatically/43327716#43327716

Comment: Thanks! Could you post an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phonegap build app - inappbrowser window is not shown automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316548/phonegap-build-app-inappbrowser-window-is-not-shown-automatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `gap:` in the `default-src` of your `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag in your `index.html`.

This is because on iOS 10 Apple got stricter with the CSP, and `*` doesn't cover some things

Comment: Where can I read more about this? If I had not posted this question here I would not have thought to look at the `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag.

Comment: About Apple being stricter, there is no information about it, it might even be a bug, in fact it was even worse on the first iOS 10 betas, but Apple doesn't provide any information about it, people found out by testing. About the CSP in general, there is some information on the whitelist plugin documentation https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#content-security-policy, there is mentioned that gap: is required for plugins to work when using the UIWebView (default). This is also useful for configuring the CSP properly https://content-security-policy.com/