# Why ios plugins are not included to build?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

Just trying to build ios version of app but plugins was not ... included? Android version runs fine and in Plugins list are also listed as installed.

Tried different projects, different configs, different syntaxes of config.xml... nothing works. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: They are probably installed, but not working because of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326912/links-in-ios-ionic-app-not-opening-immediately/43340858#43340858. Also, you are using very old versions of the plugins with the deprecated id

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `org.apache.cordova.console` is `cordova-plugin-console`.

Similary for `org.apache.cordova.device` it is `cordova-plugin-device` and so on.

1. Check your plugin list by `cordova plugin list`
2. Remove iOS platform by `cordova platform remove ios`, add it again and build it.

It should work. Good luck.