# cordova-plugin-inappbrowser not opening links from APP to IOS Device default Browser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Search a lot, but not able to find the correct solution.

```
I am trying to open links from my app to default browser of my IOS device,
```

but its not working. Its perfectly working with my android device.

- My plugin is installed properly, ( i can see that in cordova plugin list on my app)

  followed are the syntaxes, which i have tried:

  window.open(this.href, '_system');

  window.open(this.href, '_blank', {closebuttoncaption: 'Close', toolbar: 'yes', 'location=yes'});

  window.open(this.href, '_blank', {closebuttoncaption: 'Close', toolbar: 'yes'});

  window.open(this.href, '_system', 'location=yes')

  same solution with cordova.InAppBrowser.open, this as starting syntax.

  along with that tried with controller function also

  link

  $scope.openInExternalBrowser = function (path) {

  var options = "closebuttoncaption=Close,toolbar=yes";
    if($ionicPlatform.is('ios') == true){

  ```
  window.open(path, '_blank', {'closebuttoncaption': 'Close', 'toolbar':'yes', 'location=yes'});
  ```

  }else{
  window.open(path, '_system', 'location=yes');
    }
  }

So looking for some proper solution, which will work.

Thanks & Regards,

Sopo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after lot of research and thousand of builds, this post helped me to solve the issue.

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326912/links-in-ios-ionic-app-not-opening-immediately)

with the help of "cordova-plugin-whitelist" plugin. 
You need to add "gap:" after default-src attribute, your CSP meta.
=> default-src gap: *;

Thanks StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Welcome Buddy :-)

Answer (score 0):

I simply use this for my project and confirm it's work

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://google.com','_self')
```

Comment: Is it properly opening links to Browser from your IOS device & IOS Simulator?

Comment: Is there is any setting in ionic cordova, which is controlling IOS app to stop opening link outside ?